# Query to find the customer with highest amount of total purchases

Tags: mysql, sql

My relationship schema looks something like this :

[image]

Now I am trying to write a SQL query to *find the customer who has the **highest total amount of purchases** in the year 2016*. I want to know the customer name and the total amount of purchases.

```
Select Customer_name, TotalAmountOfAllHisPurchases from ...
```

I cannot think of a neat way of doing this. Anyone who can help me get started on this please?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following query should work to identify the customer name with the highest **amount** derived from all orders in the current calendar year:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_NAME, Y.QNTY 
FROM CUSTOMER_T CUST,
(
  SELECT X.CUSTOMER_ID, X.QNTY, MAX(X.QNTY) MAXAMT
  FROM (
        SELECT ORD.CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(OLN.QUANTITY * PRD.UNIT_PRICE) QNTY
        FROM ORDER_T ORD, ORDER_LINE_T OLN, PRODUCT_T PRD
        WHERE TRUNC(OLN.ORDER_DATE,'YEAR') = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR')
        AND ORD.ORDER_ID = OLN.ORDER_ID
        AND PRD.PRODUCT_ID = OLN.PRODUCT_ID
        GROUP BY ORD.CUSTOMER_ID
       ) X 
) Y
WHERE CUST.CUSTOMER_ID = Y.CUSTOMR_ID
AND Y.QNTY = Y.MAXAMT;
```

The inner-most query joins the ORDER, ORDER_LINE, and PRODUCT tables grouping by the customer ID to sum the total purchases for the current year (orders by summed amount descending). The query up one level uses the inner query results and adds on the max summed total of purchases. The outer-most query joins the CUSTOMER_T table with the inner results to get the customer Name and total order amount for all customers that match the MAXAMT value.

You may modify the date condition to always restrict to 2016 (regardless of current year) as follows:

```
WHERE TRUNC(OLN.ORDER_DATE,'YEAR') = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YEAR')
```

Write as:

```
WHERE TRUNC(OLN.ORDER_DATE,'YEAR') = TRUNC(TO_DATE('01/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YEAR')
```

You may also pull the outer query of CUSTOMER_T inside the inner table and add it to the joins. It accomplishes the same thing, but I'm not sure which is more efficient (which is applicable if your data set is large).

Note: Written from an Oracle DB perspective, hopefully this helps and you are able to convert the syntax.

Edit: I realized my suggestion would overlook multiple customers with the same total spending amount. I've reworked it to use MAX and show multiple customers (if applicable). Hope this works for your/can be converted to MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `totalPurchases` as total of Orders:

```
SELECT Customer_name, COUNT(o.order_id) as totalPurchases FROM Customer_t c
LEFT JOIN Order_t o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

Edit:

```
SELECT Customer_name, SUM(p.unity_price*ol.quantity) as totalPurchases FROM Customer_t c
LEFT JOIN Order_t o ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN Order_Line_t ol ON ol.order_id = o.order_id
LEFT JOIN Product_t p ON p.product_id = ol.product_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

Comment: Hey sorry if it was not clear. I have edited the question. I want to find the person who spent the most amount of his/her money on purchases. So you need to involve 'Unit_Price' here.

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWER WILL BE HELPFUL FOR YOU !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I did not have a mysql db installed in my device so I used the ONLINE 
TRY-IT-YOURSELF mysql editor at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

As I used the TIY editor I could not change the table names but I could find similar table structure with what you have given

### select * from customers  ----->>>> YOUR Customer_t

CustomerID ||
CustomerName
.

### select * from orders ----->>> YOUR Order_t

CustomerID ||
OrderID
.

### select * from  orderdetails ----->>>> YOUR Order_Line_t

OrderID ||
ProductID ||
Quantity
.

### select * from products ---->>>> YOUR Product_t

ProductID ||
Price

```
with 
table1 as (select o.CustomerID, o.orderid,
(
select sum(od.Quantity * p.Price) from orderdetails od, products p
where od.ProductID = p.ProductID and od.orderid = o.orderid group by od.orderid) as total
from orders o  group by o.orderid, o.CustomerID )-- having o.CustomerID in(4,10))
select c.CustomerName,sum(t1.total) as total_purchases from table1 t1,customers c 
where t1.customerid = c.customerid  group by t1.customerid having total_purchases =



(with 
table1 as (select o.CustomerID, o.orderid,
(
select sum(od.Quantity * p.Price) from orderdetails od, products p
where od.ProductID = p.ProductID and od.orderid = o.orderid group by od.orderid) as total
from orders o  group by o.orderid, o.CustomerID )-- having o.CustomerID in(4,10))
select sum(t1.total) as total_purchases from table1 t1,customers c 
where t1.customerid = c.customerid  group by t1.customerid order by total_purchases desc
LIMIT 1)
```

**This Query lists all the Customer Names & Purchase Amount of All customers with the Maximum Purchase**

Comment: Two Group By statements are used here - so this is the correct one.

1st is to sum the purchases orderid wise ( 1 order id = n products (quantity*price).

2nd is to sum the purchases customerid wise (1 customer = n orders)

3rd is to take only the maximum purchase amount (using order by desc and LIMIT 1) and take all the customers with sum of all purchases which equals to the maximum (as more than 1 customer can have the same total amount)