# Sum on multi-joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have 4 tables

```
customers
sales
sale_items
stock_items
```

I want to list all my customers. For each customer I want the total amount purchased - a field that I want the sql query to create (xxx as totalSales)

I tried selecting customers as the primary table and joining other tables on it. I tried selecting sales as the primary table and also the sale_items. I kind of got the correct sum calculation but it will show me the first customer first.

This is what my tables look like:

```
*TABLE customers*
id
customer_name
email

*TABLE sales*
id
customer_id
transaction_date

*TABLE sale_items*
id
sale_id
stock_item_id

*TABLE stock_items*
id
item_name
price
```

I want to

- Create a list of all customers, sorted by the customer with the most sales (in value) first. Not the count of the sales, but the total amount (sales value) of the sales
- Display the items purchased per customer under the customer name. This would not be per order, but for all sales. So if a tin of coffee was purchased by customer X, over a count of 4 orders each, the tin of coffee would display 4 times. Though if possible I'd like the items listed a-z.

I have inner joined the tables on each other, so I would get a list of all transactions. I've tried SELECT * FROM customers, tried FROM sales, tried from sale_items. I've tried GROUP_BY customer_id, but then I would get incorrect counts.

I want to display the data as such.

```
CUSTOMER                    ITEMS                   TOTAL VALUE
John Doe                    Coffee
                            Milk
                            Tea
                            Milk
                            Bread
                            Coffee                  500

Jane Doe                    Coffee
                            Milk
                            Coke                    350

Denver Doe                  Coffee
                            Milk
                            Bread
                            Bread                   125
```

I don't want to use PHP and make a query for every single "thing". I am trying to run one or two queries.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550294/query-to-find-the-customer-with-highest-amount-of-total-purchases

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to quite get them in separate rows like you're showing (unless you look into the `ROLLUP` function), but that's probably not a requirement for you.

I think you should use `GROUP_CONCAT` which is an aggregation function sort of like `SUM` but it creates a comma separated list out of all of the values:

```
SELECT 
*
SUM(sale_amount) as total_sales,
GROUP_CONCAT(item_name) as item_names
FROM customers c
JOIN sales s USING (customer_id)
JOIN sale_items si USING (sale_id)
JOIN stock_items sit USING (stock_item_id)
GROUP BY customer_id
```

What you should see as a sample row is:

```
Denver Doe     Coffee,Milk,Bread,Bread     125
```

(I had to make up some column names, like sale_amount, but you must have those in there I'm sure. You'll have to make some adjustments in those names and maybe in how I did the joins as well, but this should work with some changes if I'm understanding your needs).